# OpenCV error when trying to capture frame every seconds

Tags: python, opencv, runtime-error

I am trying to capture an image every 5 seconds in Opencv using my webcam however I am getting an error whenever I try.

Python Code:

```py
def imgcap():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    framerate = cap.get(5)
    x=1

    while(True):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            # Our operations on the frame come here

            filename = 'Captures/capture' +  str(int(x)) + ".png"
            x=x+1
            cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)
            time.sleep(5)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            print("Ret False")

    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

imgcap()

imgcap()
```

Error I am Getting:

```
  File "vision.py", line 30, in <module>
    imgcap()
  File "vision.py", line 21, in imgcap
    cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-oduouqig\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:753: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you release the `cap` instance inside the loop. You wouldn't be able to read from `cap` from the 2nd iteration:

```
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    # comment this
    # cap.release()
    # Our operations on the frame come here

    filename = 'Captures/capture' +  str(int(x)) + ".png"
    #... other code
```

Comment: So delete the first `cap.release()`. The one right after `ret, frame = cap.read()`?

Comment: @Reacher42 yes, only release the instance when you are done with it, i.e. keep the one before `cv2.destroyAllWindows()`. Also check if `ret == True` to see if `cap.read()` is successful.

Comment: Whenever I run that code(I updated it in the post) it just sites on my command line running infinitley. what did I do wrong?

Comment: You can (only) break the loop by pressing the `q` key as indicated by your code.

Comment: But the window where it should be shown isn't even popping up anymore, leading me to believe that there is an issue

Comment: What window? You don’t have any cv2.imshow in your code.

Comment: Oh Duh, thanks for the help. However when I press q it isn't stopping. I am having to close my powershell to get it to stop

Comment: Probably because you don’t have any imshow. waitKey only waits on imshow windows :)

Comment: Ok I fixed that problem. Thanks for the help